# How to get Locale from userprofile information from TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

How to get Locale from userprofile information from TFS? I couldnot find any information in MSDN and internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not documented, however you can track the API with third tools such as [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or directly press F12 in Chrome.

You can use below REST API to get the user profile:

```
GET http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_api/_common/GetUserProfile?__v=5
```

For the Locale information, seems we can only get the `Language` and `Time zone` by the "`LCID`" and "`TimeZoneId`" (*Ctrl + F -> Enter the LCID or TimeZoneId to find out the locale info*).

The `Date pattern` and `Time pattern` are not recorded in JSON response, the value is `null` for both of them.

See below example with the screenshot:

```
    "TimeZoneId": "Central Asia Standard Time",
    "LCID": 1033,
```

[image]

Comment: @Manikanta Cv Have you resolved the issue by the answer above? any update?

Comment: Dear Andy, thank you for your answer. It has definitely provided me an insight about how to access user profiles. Posting another related question. request you to take a a look at it.